# Subversion timed commit

Tags: windows, svn, autocommit

I've got a folder under version control; the contents aren't source, but they are binaries that are modified frequently and would generally get committed once a day.

Problem is, the consumers of those files can't grasp the concept for source control, they don't realistically have access to the folder in question and 'they can't be bothered' to commit once a day.

What I'd like to do, is have an auto-commit, once a day (4 am) of that folder. Are there any existing tools, or do I have to write one?

Comment: I'm slightly confused. You say the consumers don't realistically have access to the folder, but apparently they can change the binaries? Could you elaborate on the workflow a bit?

Comment: It's a shared folder on the network that is used by a piece of software that they use. They don't actually navigate to the folder at all or see it.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an auto-commit using `cron` or `at` and a script file calling the appropriate `svn ci` commands on each client PC. Auto-committing is not a good idea IMO:

- Broken, unfinished code might get checked in
- any changes will not be documented

but I understand from your description that this may not matter in your case.

Comment: I'll take a look at this for sure. I should have tagged this as a windows environment, but I'll look at a windows scheduled task. You're correct in that the problems you describe don't apply. The files aren't code at all (images etc.) and the number of files and their names never change.